# Commit cannot be completed due to rebalance

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My Kafka consumer code is as shown below and I have only one consumer!

```
Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667");
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-group");
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(consumerConfig);
        TestConsumerRebalanceListener rebalanceListener = new TestConsumerRebalanceListener();
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test1"), rebalanceListener);
        HDFSAppendTrial example = new HDFSAppendTrial();
        String coreSite = "/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml";
        String hdfsSite = "/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml";
        String hdfsFilePath = "/appendTo/Trial.csv";

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(999999999);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                FileSystem fileSystem = example.configureFileSystem(coreSite, hdfsSite);
                String res = example.appendToFile(fileSystem, record.value(), hdfsFilePath);
                System.out.printf("%s\n", record.value());
                if (res.equalsIgnoreCase( "success")) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully appended to file");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("couldn't append to file");
                example.closeFileSystem(fileSystem);

            }
            consumer.commitSync();


        }
```

Am getting the following error after streaming some number of records

[image]

How to resolve the above issue and explain me causes of the issue, how to overcome such ! Can someone help me out code a consumer with some more requirements I have.

Thanks in Advance for the one who could help me out and also to the one who give at least a try

Answer (score 1):

---

```
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,"True");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"99998");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,"10000");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"99999");
```

---

I was able to fix this by adding  the above properties in properties object, **consumerConfig**